# Visualization in azure iot central

Tags: azure-iot-central

In azure IoT central, there are 3 modes of visualization:

1) Stacked
2) Unstacked
3) Shared

I understood stacked but what is the use for Unstacked and Shared?
What is meant by this "A graph for every measure is plotted against one Y-axis, but the values for the Y-axis are changed based on the **highlighted measure**."

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Unstacked**:In this visualization mode, every measure is plotted against the Y-axis, but the scale is not fixed, it will be changed when you focus the measure to highlighted in the graphic.

**Shared Y-axis**: It means every measure is plotted against one Y-axis, and the scale for Y-axis is fixed, it would not change. For example, if you are comparing the temperature of two device over the past day, you can create a chart that shows the temperature for each device on a single chart with the same X and Y axes.

The main difference between Shared and Unstacked mode is the scale of Y-axis, one is fixed while another one is dynamic.You can compare the difference from the following image.
[image]

Comment: Any way to set Shared as the default for dashboard charts?